# InvalidResourceReference when deploying ARM template for VM

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager

I downloaded ARM template from Azure for deploying VM. I did not modify the script in any way. When I run the `deploy.ps1` script I get the following error

`New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 1:05:56 PM - Resource Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces 'win2016vm293' failed
with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidResourceReference",
    "message": "Resource /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/win2016vm2/providers/Micros
oft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/Win2016vm2-nsg referenced by resource /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/Win2016FromScript/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/win2016vm293 was not found.
Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.",
    "details": []
  }
}'`

The following is the template.js file.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualMachineSize": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "networkInterfaceName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "addressPrefix": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetPrefix": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicIpAddressName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicIpAddressType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicIpAddressSku": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoShutdownStatus": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoShutdownTime": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoShutdownTimeZone": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoShutdownNotificationStatus": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "vnetId": "[resourceId('win2016vm2','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
                    "windowsConfiguration": {
                        "provisionVmAgent": "true"
                    }
                },
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                        "offer": "WindowsServer",
                        "sku": "2016-Datacenter",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "fromImage",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataDisks": []
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat('shutdown-computevm-', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules",
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-26-preview",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownStatus')]",
                "taskType": "ComputeVmShutdownTask",
                "dailyRecurrence": {
                    "time": "[parameters('autoShutdownTime')]"
                },
                "timeZoneId": "[parameters('autoShutdownTimeZone')]",
                "targetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
                "notificationSettings": {
                    "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownNotificationStatus')]",
                    "timeInMinutes": "30"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "[parameters('addressPrefix')]"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix')]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIpAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('win2016vm2','Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "enableAcceleratedNetworking": true,
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('win2016vm2', 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIpAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIpAddressType')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressSku')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "RDP",
                        "properties": {
                            "priority": 300,
                            "protocol": "TCP",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "direction": "Inbound",
                            "sourceApplicationSecurityGroups": [],
                            "destinationApplicationSecurityGroups": [],
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "3389"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
        }
    }
}
```

After running the script I see that only `Win2016vm2-nsg` (Network security group), as well as the IP and the VNet resources are created.

In the template, the section for creating `Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces` contains `dependsOn` section with `networkSecurityGroups` resource name in it, which seems correct. So I'm not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is using hardcoded resourceGroup name for several resources, you need to amend that, change `'win2016vm2'` to a resourceGroup you are deploying to, or remove resourceGroup from `resourceId()` function altogether.

Comment: That was it. Thanks. It's unfortunate that the template was generated by Azure and cannot be used after it was generated - either through script or directly in Azure portal.

Comment: autogenerated templates are just garbage, dont waste time on them.